# access an array in another script with variable name?

Tags: c#, arrays, variables, unity-game-engine

Im very new in programming and i need help to solve a problem that arise.
Im trying to access an array in another script and generally there is no problem. But my Situation ist this:

For Example:

Script A contains a few Arrays with different non numerical names.

```
   using UnityEngine;
   using System.Collections;
   using System.Collections.Generic;

   public class ScriptA : MonoBehaviour {
   public int[] keys = new int[4];
   public int[] screws= new int[4];
   public int[] nails= new int[4];
   public int[] iron= new int[4];
   ....
   }
```

Now in Script B i need to access these arrays but with an variable. How can i do this?

For Example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ScriptB: MonoBehaviour {
    ScriptA scriptA;
    public string arrayName;    // Here user could type in the name of an array



    void Start()
    {
        scriptA = GameObject.Find("Object").GetComponent<ScriptA>();

        // This try to access the array of course not works. But how?
        scriptA.arrayname;   
    }
```

Thanks for ideas and solutions. I think its not a hard problem, but i have no idea to solve it.

Comment: If you want to access for example `keys` you can do it with `scriptA.keys` or an individual element `scriptA.keys[0]`.

Comment: yeah I know but i need to access the array with the string variable "arrayName" from ScriptB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need reflection (ugly), or you can define a `Dictionary<string, int[]>` in `ScriptA`, like this:

```
public class ScriptA : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int[] keys = new int[4];
    public int[] screws = new int[4];
    public int[] nails = new int[4];
    public int[] iron = new int[4];
    public Dictionary<string, int[]> arrays;

    void Start()
    {
        arrays = new Dictionary<string, int[]>
        {
            { "keys", keys },
            { "screws", screws },
            { "nails", nails },
            { "iron", iron }
        };
    }
}
```

And then you use it in `ScriptB` like this: `scriptA.arrays[arrayName]`.

Comment: thats what im looking for. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Do the arrays need to be static to implement them in the dictionary? This wouldnt be good.

Comment: As far as I know, they don't need to be static. Are you getting a compiler error?

Comment: Yes. With the code below i got this error : "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'ScriptA.keys'". If i change the keys Array to static it works fine, but i dont want this array static.

Comment: Now it uses the `Start` method to create the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not something you're after but what you're trying to do (from what I infer) is make compiler let you add a dynamic property to a class with unknown type. As far as I'm aware of C# this is not possible. What you can do to work around this is you could basically have a method in your so called ScriptA that would accept a string parameter with one of the following internal functionality

```
 public object GetPropertyValue(string propName){
     switch (propName){
        case: "keys"
          //do whatever you need to do with keys
        //and so on
     }
 }
```

or

A: if you encapsulate those fields inside properties then

```
 public object GetPropertyValue(string propName){
      System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi= (typeof(ScriptA)).GetProperty(propName);
      pi.GetValue(this,null);
 }
```

B: if you don't want to encapsulate them then

```
 public object GetFieldValue(string fieldName){
      System.Reflection.FieldInfo fi= (typeof(ScriptA)).GetField(fieldName);
      fi.GetValue(this,null);
 }
```

Read more about [PropertyInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) and [FieldInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Aren't `keys`, `screws`, `nails` and `iron` fields, instead of properties? Does `PropertyInfo` work with those too?

Comment: Umm, yeah, really. Somehow I forgot about this. Thanks I edited the question. But anyway, the convention in C# is to not expose fields to public but instead have them in private and let others access them through properties.

Comment: Unity (which this question uses) doesn't seem to follow all C# conventions.